# Using gdal to convert from UTM to equidistant lat/lon

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude, utm

I am getting rather confused with converting a UTM gridded dataset into a equidistant/rectangular latlon gridded dataset. Can anybody help me?

I have a UTM set with the following projection:

```
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 18N",
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",-75],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","32618"]]
Origin = (556950.000000000000000,5573990.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (90.000000000000000,-90.000000000000000)
Metadata:
 AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
 INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  556950.000, 5573990.000) ( 74d12' 0.38"W, 50d18'54.95"N)
Lower Left  (  556950.000, 4905470.000) ( 74d17' 9.82"W, 44d18' 0.91"N)
Upper Right (  655950.000, 5573990.000) ( 72d48'37.20"W, 50d17'50.61"N)
Lower Right (  655950.000, 4905470.000) ( 73d 2'43.67"W, 44d17' 8.74"N)
Center      (  606450.000, 5239730.000) ( 73d35'30.62"W, 47d18' 8.60"N)
Band 1 Block=1100x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

And want to convert this to a rectangular latlon set (with corners just as they are provided in the corner coordinates. What to do? I am sure it should be easy...The biggest problem is that if I directly convert this into latlon, it won't be equidistant...

Comment: Hmm, it seems that I already answered my own question: does just gdalwarp -t_srs WGS84 source.tif output.tif suffice? :)

Comment: You will not get exactly the same corners, because a UTM rectangle gets squeezed in degree coordinates.